# Using special auto start servlet to initialize on startup and share application data

Tags: servlets, initialization, data-sharing

I need to get some configuration and connect to external resources/objects/systems somewhere and store it in application scope.

I can see two ways to setup my application:

- Overriding the `init()` in the existing servlets and required code there and keeping all constructed objects inside that same servlet.
- Having some kind of an initialisation servlet and using its `init()` to do the work. Then storing created objects in `ServletContext` to share it with my other servlets.

Which out of above is better approach? Is there any better way to share objects between servlets? Calling them directly from one another or so...?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

None of both is the better approach. Servlets are intended to listen on HTTP events (HTTP requests), not on deployment events (startup/shutdown).

---

### CDI/EJB unavailable? Use [`ServletContextListener`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/servletcontextlistener)

```
@WebListener
public class Config implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // Do stuff during webapp's startup.
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // Do stuff during webapp's shutdown.
    }

}
```

If you're not on Servlet 3.0 yet and can't upgrade (it would be about time because Servlet 3.0 was introduced more than a decade ago), and thus can't use `@WebListener` annotation, then you need to manually register it in `/WEB-INF/web.xml` like below:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.example.Config</listener-class>
</listener>
```

To store and obtain objects in the application scope (so that all servlets can access them), use [`ServletContext#setAttribute()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/servletcontext#setAttribute(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object)) and [`#getAttribute()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/servletcontext#getAttribute(java.lang.String)).

Here's an example which lets the listener store itself in the application scope:

```
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        event.getServletContext().setAttribute("config", this);
        // ...
    }
```

and then obtain it in a servlet:

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Config config = (Config) getServletContext().getAttribute("config");
        // ...
    }
```

It's also available in JSP EL by `${config}`. So you could make it a simple bean as well.

---

### CDI available? Use [`@Observes`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/3.0/apidocs/jakarta/enterprise/event/observes) on [`ApplicationScoped.class`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/3.0/apidocs/jakarta/enterprise/context/applicationscoped)

```
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped; // And thus NOT e.g. jakarta.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped

@ApplicationScoped
public class Config {

    public void init(@Observes @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class) ServletContext context) {
        // Do stuff during webapp's startup.
    }

    public void destroy(@Observes @Destroyed(ApplicationScoped.class) ServletContext context) {
        // Do stuff during webapp's shutdown.
    }
}
```

This is available in a servlet via `@Inject`. Make it if necessary also `@Named` so it's available via `#{config}` in EL as well.

Noted should be that this is new since CDI 1.1. If you're still on CDI 1.0 and can't upgrade, then pick another approach.

In case you're curious how to install CDI on a non-JEE server such as Tomcat, head to: [How to install and use CDI on Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995951/how-to-install-and-use-cdi-on-tomcat)

---

### EJB available? Consider [`@Startup`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/enterprise-beans/4.0/apidocs/jakarta/ejb/startup)[`@Singleton`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/enterprise-beans/4.0/apidocs/jakarta/ejb/singleton)

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class Config {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // Do stuff during webapp's startup.
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        // Do stuff during webapp's shutdown.
    }
}
```

This is available in a servlet via `@EJB`. The difference with other approaches is that it's by default transactional and in case of `@Singleton` also read/write locked. So if you would ever need to inject a random EJB (e.g. `@Stateless`) into a `@WebListener` or an `@ApplicationScoped` then you could basically as good merge both into a single `@Startup @Singleton`.

#### See also:

- [How to run a background task in a servlet based web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691132/how-to-run-a-background-task-in-a-servlet-application/)
- [ServletContainerInitializer vs ServletContextListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10776599/servletcontainerinitializer-vs-servletcontextlistener/)
- [How do I force an application-scoped bean to instantiate at application startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600534/how-do-i-force-an-application-scoped-bean-to-instantiate-at-application-startup/)

Comment: Just a note in case somebody encounters a similar issue: It seems that you have to register the `<listener>` in `/WEB-INF/web.xml` before you register the servlets. I didn't know that. Also, GWT could have problems with the annotation approach, so it'd be best to manually register `<listener>` instead of relying on the annotation, even if no error is given by the IDE.