# Background timer task in JSP/Servlet web application

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, scheduled-tasks, background-process

I want to retrieve from subscription and store feeds to DB from subscription after every 6 hours. I want to have a timer thread in background to accomplish this task.

What's the best way? A normal timer thread or Quartz API?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

To start, I wouldn't use JSP for this. There it is not for.

When you're on Java EE 5, use the container-provided jobscheduling APIs for this. Further detail depends on the container you're using. JBoss AS 5 for example ships with Quartz out the box. Or when you're using a framework on top of JSP/Servlet which offers jobscheduling APIs, like as [Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html), then you should use it.

If there are none (e.g. you're using just Tomcat 6), or you want to be independent from the container and/or framework, create a [`ServletContextListener`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) with a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). Further detail can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691132/how-to-keep-the-servlet-continously-running/4691650#4691650).

Or when you're already on a Java EE 6 container which supports EJB 3.1 (JBoss AS 6, GlassFish 3, but thus *not* Tomcat 7), easiest is to create a [`@Singleton`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Singleton.html) EJB with [`@Schedule`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Schedule.html) method.

```
@Singleton
public class UpdateSubscriptions {

    @Schedule(hour="*/6", minute="0", second="0", persistent=false)
    public void run() {
        // Do your job here.
    }

}
```

That's it. No further configuration is necessary.

---

**Update**: as per the comments, you're using Tomcat (6 or 7?). To start a thread during webapp's startup which runs the task every 6 hours, use the example as provided in the [beforelinked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691132/how-to-keep-the-servlet-continously-running/4691650#4691650) and make the following change in the [`scheduleAtFixedRate()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) method

```
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new UpdateSubscriptions(), 0, 6, TimeUnit.HOURS);
```

The class `UpdateSubscriptions` must implement [`Runnable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) and the actual job needs to be done in the [`run()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html#run%28%29) method which you [`@Override`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html), like as in the example in the linked answer.

Comment: +1 can't get an answer any perfect than this.

Comment: I am using Tomcat only. I saw the linked answer too. 1. I intended to use it in a class, was crntlt not going to use JSP. But, is servlet a better way? 2. if i put it in a servlet as shown in linked answer won't it create new thread every 6 hours?

Comment: It's not a servlet. It's a listener. And there's only one instance of it in webapp's lifetime (the same applies to servlets by the way).

Comment: I imagine that you've possibly a hard time in setting the `scheduleAtFixedRate()` method. I've updated the answer with an example which runs the `UpdateSubscriptions` instance every 6 hours.

Comment: By using the EB scheduler, you'll be limited to the restrictions of EJBs. Hence, if you need to use something like a multithreaded HttpClient, you shouldn't do it using an EJB timer as it may cause the threads to get screwed up.