# Listeners for changes to app config/resources files

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have an app running in tomcat6 which reads a resource file (a simple text file, no xml) at startup to configure/instantiate some classes. Now I want to be able to modify that file and the changes to be reflected in the app without having to restart the server. Is there a way to do that?

Basically if I could define and attach a listener to that resource, that's all I need.

Answer (score 1):

Try one of the following:

- [jpoller](http://jpoller.sourceforge.net/)
- [JNotify](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/)
- [Java Native Access (JNA)](http://jna.java.net/)
- [Roll your own thread](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0490.html)

**NOTE**

With Java 7, [Watching a Directory for Changes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) becomes part of the standard API.

Answer (score 0):

Programatically you can trgger a service which will refresh those classes with new files

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a built in resource listener, but it would be fairly simple to start a new thread that monitors the file in the file system ( on date/time last updated for example ) and refreshed the classes if it changed.

Answer (score 0):

Start a timer in the web app which gets the resource file as below:

In a ServletContextListener.contextInitialized(),

```
package com.servlets;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

public class WatcherListener
    implements ServletContextListener
{
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event)
{
    ServletContext servletContext = event.getServletContext();
    Timer timer = new Timer("ResourceListener");
    timer.schedule(new MyWatcherTask(servletContext), 15);
}

public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event)
{
}

private class MyWatcherTask extends TimerTask
{
    private final ServletContext servletContext;
    private long lastModifiedTime = -1;

    public MyWatcherTask(ServletContext servletContext)
    {
        this.servletContext = servletContext;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        URL resource = null;
        try {
            resource = servletContext.getResource("resouceFileName");
            File resourceFile = new File(resource.toString());
            long current = resourceFile.lastModified();
            if (current > lastModifiedTime) {
                reloadReources();
            }
            lastModifiedTime = current;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
}
```

The above code is just a template

Comment: You should prefer `ScheduledExecutorService` over `TimerTask`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409932/java-timer-vs-executorservice and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798688/reload-servlet-once-a-month. Or when you're on Java EE 6 with EJB capable container, prefer `@Singleton` with `@Schedule`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357033/background-timer-task-in-jsp-web-application.