# How to set a global clock in a servlet container to check expiration date in database

Tags: mysql, servlets, timer

I'm developing this website which works like a kind of auction for specific kind of items.
The website will be developed using pure jsp and servlets.
Basically the items that the sellers will post on the site have an expiry date, after that date "1 minute after midnight of the selected expiry date" the product will be assigned to the highest offering user or registered as unsold.
The items will be stored in a MySQL database with a Date column.
I need to find a way to automatically find out when an auction for an item is expired, i was thinking of a Timer object within the servlet container that every day one minute after midnight sends a query to the DB to check which auction is expired and to take an action accordingly.
Before to start working on it i wanted to check rather there are better "known" options.
Any idea?
Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [background Timer task in jsp web application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357033/background-timer-task-in-jsp-web-application)

Answer (score 0):

[Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) Scheduler are better suited.

> Quartz is a full-featured, open source job scheduling service that can
>   be integrated with, or used along side virtually any Java EE or Java
>   SE application - from the smallest stand-alone application to the
>   largest e-commerce system. Quartz can be used to create simple or
>   complex schedules for executing tens, hundreds, or even
>   tens-of-thousands of jobs; jobs whose tasks are defined as standard
>   Java components that may execute virtually anything you may program
>   them to do. The Quartz Scheduler includes many enterprise-class
>   features, such as JTA transactions and clustering.

Comment: It seems OP needs to execute some timely batch jobs..so its better to use Quartz

Comment: need to do it without external services

Comment: Quartz can be integrated in your servlet. That way it's not really an external service..