# How can I schedule a task to run every X hours on my tomcat server?

Tags: javascript, jsp, tomcat, scheduling

I have a webpage in javascript mainly that has an export to excel function.

How can I schedule that function to run and save in a spacific folder on that server every 2 hours for example?

Comment: The excel is saved on the server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [background Timer task in jsp web application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357033/background-timer-task-in-jsp-web-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this sounds like you've already built everything and just want to automate it, here is an idea:

- Set up a Quartz job to run every 2 hours.  [Example here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/quartz-scheduler-example/)
- Use Rhino to run your JavaScript inside the JVM.  [Example here](http://weblog.raganwald.com/2007/07/javascript-on-jvm-in-fifteen-minutes.html).  OTOH, you could translate your JS code to Java and just run it natively without Rhino.
- Take the output of the JS method and save it to the server.

There are probably a billion other ways to do it...

Answer (score 1):

```
   new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask(){
      @Override
      public void run()
      {
        //export Excel here
      }
    }, 0, 1000*60*60*2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the scheduling to be controlled by the client, than you could either use a meta refresh tag, or a simple settimeout js call.

If you want the scheduling to be controlled on the server, you could create a TimerTask on the the server.

I'd create a warpper class the would not only create the TimerTask but manage it\them (if for instance a timer should be created per user or dispose by a user request)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do with is use the Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate() method.  This is if you don't want to import any third party libraries for whatever reason.  Some of them are quite good though!

```
Timer timer = new Timer("TEST", true);
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TestTimer(), INITIAL_DELAY, INTERVAL_PERIOD);
```

Where you define your TestTimer (TestTimer extends TimerTask) to export the Excel and INITIAL_DELAY is the time when it should first fire and INTERVAL_PERIOD is the time when it should try exporting to Excel again.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html