# How to configue cron job for jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp, cron, crontrigger

I need to execute a jsp page after every 30 minutes. I am using glassfish server. I want to uses cron job for that, but I never work before with cron job.

Please give me any link or example from where I can understand how to configure a cron job for jsp page and execute it after a specific time period?

thanks in advance,
Enamul

Comment: possible duplicate of [Background timer task in JSP/Servlet web application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357033/background-timer-task-in-jsp-servlet-web-application) By the way, you need to redesign your JSP page first. [JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info) is intented to generate HTML, [not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) to run business code.

Comment: What does "execute a jsp page" mean here?  Do you want to send it an HTTP GET/POST request?  What do you want to do with the output?

Comment: i want to check the database after a specific time that any new row is inserted or not. if yes than I need to create a csv file and insert those new rows into tha csv file.

Comment: Sounds like you just want a background process, not a JSP.

Comment: yeah, it's like background process and I want use JSP for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to cause the webserver to "execute" a JSP page, you need to send the webserver a suitable HTTP request.  The simplest way to do this is to use a command line tool like `wget` or `curl` (or the Windoze alternatives).  Once you can do that successfully, it is a simple matter to turn that into a `cron` job.

Refer to:

- The documentation of your webserver / webapp to find out what URL to use, the HTTP method type to use, what parameters to send, and so on.
- The manual entry for `wget(1)` or `curl(1)` for how to use these commands.
- The manual entries for `crontab(1)` and `crontab(5)` to find out how to create a cron job.

Trying to do this in Java is most likely going to make the task more complicated than it needs to be.