# Running a service in the background in Java EE

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, notifications, jersey

**The whole picture:** We have a restful web service working with Jersey, now we want it to send Email Notifications at specified times which include specified dates and also after specified events.

**The Problem:** The first idea and design that we came up with, was to design a notification center with the responsibility of sending those notification emails whenever we need them. However, we have to write some kind of a "controller" to watch the date and events (based on a database) to determine the time and details of the required notification and hand it over to the notification center to send it.

**The Question:** Now the question we have is how to write such a "controller" class and how to make it always run in the background.

Comment: 1) What do you mean by background? 2) Take a look at [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)

Comment: Are you really using J2EE? Jersey was never been part of J2EE, but was introduced in Java EE. In any case ... Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357033/background-timer-task-in-jsp-servlet-web-application/5357856#5357856