# Sending email on particular day

Tags: java, email, date

I want to send email using Java code. I am using `smtp.gmail.com` for sending the mail and it's working fine. Now I want to send email on particular day of every month say 1st of every month. I have searched a lot but not working for me.

Below is my code for sending mail.

```
public class sendMailUsingTimeInterval{
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
     String[] to={"to@gmail.com"};
     String[] cc={"cc@gmail.com"};
     String subject = "hello";
     String body = "Thanks , this is test.....!!";

     //This is for google
             sendMail("from@gmail.com","password","smtp.gmail.com","465","true",
     "true",true,"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory","false",to,cc,
     subject,body);
 }
 public synchronized static boolean sendMail(String userName,String passWord,String host,String port,String starttls,String auth,boolean debug,String socketFactoryClass,String fallback,String[] to,String[] cc,String subject,String text)
    {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        //Properties props=System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", userName);
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        if(!"".equals(port))
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
        if(!"".equals(starttls))
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable",starttls);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", auth);
        if(debug){
        props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
        }
        else
        {
        props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "false");         
        }
        if(!"".equals(port))
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", port);
        if(!"".equals(socketFactoryClass))
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",socketFactoryClass);
        if(!"".equals(fallback))
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", fallback);

        try
        {
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        session.setDebug(debug);
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setContent(text,"text/html");
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from@gmail.com"));
        for(int i=0;i<to.length;i++)
        {
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to[i]));
        }
        for(int i=0;i<cc.length;i++)
        {
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress(cc[i]));
        }
        msg.saveChanges();
        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(host, userName, passWord);
        transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
        return true;
        }
        catch (Exception mex)
        {
        mex.printStackTrace();
        return false;
        }
    }
```

The code is working when this class is called. Would really appreciate if someone could tell me how to implement it in such a way that message is sent automatically on 1st of every month.

Comment: Probably you want to do scheduling through your OS, rather than in the code.

Comment: There is no need to add the major tag in the title.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you've tried to solve this problem. Can you explain what your research has discovered and share any implementation attempts?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Annotation Type Schedule"

@Target(value=METHOD)
@Retention(value=RUNTIME)
public @interface Schedule
Schedule a timer for automatic creation with a timeout schedule based on a cron-like time expression. The annotated method is used as the timeout callback method.

All elements of this annotation are optional. If none are specified a persistent timer will be created with callbacks occuring every day at midnight in the default time zone associated with the container in which the application is executing...

Documentation - http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Schedule.html

Example - https://stackoverflow.com/a/7499769/1490962

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5357856/1490962

http://ci.apache.org/projects/openejb/examples-generated/schedule-methods/

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something that you can do through the mail APIs directly, you'd have to use some sort of scheduling tool (Quartz, Spring `@Scheduled`, or similar) to call `sendMail` at the appropriate times with the appropriate parameters.