# How to run a background task in a servlet based web application?

Tags: multithreading, jakarta-ee, servlets, background-process, scheduledexecutorservice

I'm using Java and I want to keep a servlet continuously running in my application, but I'm not getting how to do it. My servlet has a method which gives counts of the user from a database on a daily basis as well as the total count of the users from the whole database. So I want to keep the servlet continuously running for that.

Comment: What do you mean, "continuously running"?

Comment: what do you mean by continously running? It will run as long as your app server runs

Comment: I don't understand why it has to run continuously... if someone wants the 'user count' then they call your servlet method and you give it to them?

Comment: @trojanfoe Actually i want the usercount on daily basis,so for that i will have to run the servlet manually everyday so instead of doing that i want to run the servlet contineously.so i wont need to run the servlet everyday.

Comment: @pritsag Servlets are not the way to solve this problem - if you want 'stats' collected throughout the day then use some other technology.

Comment: @skaffman,@faith Actually to get the count i will have to run the servlet manually everyday as database will be updated everyday as users will be created everyday.so instead of running servlet manually everyday i want to keep the servlet running.

Comment: @pritsag: A servlet is there to serve user requests, not to run batch jobs.

Comment: @trojanfoe can u suggest  me the other technologies ?

Comment: @pritsag If the database is accessible from the client then a simple Java program using JDBC (running from the client itself) might be appropriate.  Other than that you could try a scripting language (perl, python, etc.).  If the database is not accessible from the client then you need to create a batch architecture on the server that perhaps stores its results on the database itself - you then then use a Servlet to allow clients access these stats.

Answer (score 225, accepted):

Your problem is that you misunderstand the purpose of the [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info). It's intented to act on HTTP requests, nothing more. You want just a background task which runs once on daily basis.

#### EJB available? Use `@Schedule`

If your environment happen to support EJB (i.e. a real Java EE server such as WildFly, JBoss, TomEE, Payara, GlassFish, etc), then use [`@Schedule`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Schedule.html) instead. Here are some examples:

```
@Singleton
public class BackgroundJobManager {

    @Schedule(hour="0", minute="0", second="0", persistent=false)
    public void someDailyJob() {
        // Do your job here which should run every start of day.
    }

    @Schedule(hour="*/1", minute="0", second="0", persistent=false)
    public void someHourlyJob() {
        // Do your job here which should run every hour of day.
    }

    @Schedule(hour="*", minute="*/15", second="0", persistent=false)
    public void someQuarterlyJob() {
        // Do your job here which should run every 15 minute of hour.
    }

    @Schedule(hour="*", minute="*", second="*/5", persistent=false)
    public void someFiveSecondelyJob() {
        // Do your job here which should run every 5 seconds.
    }

}
```

Yes, that's really all. The container will automatically pickup and manage it.

#### EJB unavailable? Use `ScheduledExecutorService`

If your environment doesn't support EJB (i.e. you're not using not a real Java EE server, but a barebones servletcontainer such as Tomcat, Jetty, etc), then use [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). This can be initiated by a [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html). Here's a kickoff example:

```
@WebListener
public class BackgroundJobManager implements ServletContextListener {

    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new SomeDailyJob(), 0, 1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new SomeHourlyJob(), 0, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new SomeQuarterlyJob(), 0, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new SomeFiveSecondelyJob(), 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        scheduler.shutdownNow();
    }

}
```

Where the job classes look like this:

```
public class SomeDailyJob implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do your daily job here.
    }

}
```

```
public class SomeHourlyJob implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do your hourly job here.
    }

}
```

```
public class SomeQuarterlyJob implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do your quarterly job here.
    }

}
```

```
public class SomeFiveSecondelyJob implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do your quarterly job here.
    }

}
```

### Do not ever think about using `java.util.Timer`/`java.lang.Thread` in a Java EE / Servlet based environment

Last but not least, **never** directly use `java.util.Timer` and/or `java.lang.Thread` in Java EE. This is recipe for trouble. An elaborate explanation can be found in this JSF-related answer on the same question: [Spawning threads in a JSF managed bean for scheduled tasks using a timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499534/spawning-threads-in-a-jsf-managed-bean-for-scheduled-tasks-using-a-timer).

Comment: @BalucS Thank you sir,your solution helped me and I learned about ScheduledExecutorService which was new to me as i m new to java.Thank you once again.

Comment: @BalusC : Where should the class UpdateCounts be put in web.xml?

Comment: @Ashwin *web.xml* is a [Deployment Descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deployment_descriptor). The class *UpdateCount* is not related with deployment, so it doesn't have to be put in *web.xml*

Comment: One crucial issue with a `ScheduledExecutorService`: Be sure to **capture *all* exceptions** in your executor. If an exception escapes from your `run` method, the executor silently stops executing. This is a feature not a bug. Read the doc and study up with some googling.

Comment: Question: This task `scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new SomeDailyJob(), 0, 1, TimeUnit.DAYS);` at what time will start? at 00:00 or  every 24h from the moment the webApp will deploy in the server?

Comment: @yaylitzis: just consult Javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) (check 2nd argument)

Comment: Just to be sure.. with  `long initialDelay = 0` and `long period=1` this means at 00.00 every day right?

Comment: @BalusC, what about `org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorTask`?

Comment: I've followed through the code in your answer and used it to create a `ServletContextListener`, using the same principles to wrap the only instance of a `ScheduledExecutorService` that exists in my EE app. (There are no other places in the code in which I've used `Thread`, `Runnable` or `ScheduledExecutorService`.) However, stopping/undeploying the application still results in an error message of `SEVERE: The web application [/MyApp] appears to have started a thread named [pool-4-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.` I don't know why that happens.

Comment: Following on from my prior comment: Creating a `ThreadFactory` that sets the thread to be a daemon (`Thread t = Executors.defaultThreadFactory().newThread(runnable); t.setDaemon(true);`) and then using the created `ThreadFactory` as an argument to `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()` solves the issue for me. (The only I/O work done by the task in question is to read from a small JSON file. It uses `javax.mail` to send an email based on configuration in that file.) I'm not expecting the application to be stopped/reloaded for about a month. I don't forsee an issue with using a daemon.

Comment: @Agi: that will happen if `scheduler.shutdownNow()` is not correctly invoked as per the example. If this is not invoked, then the schedule thread will indeed keep running.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using a library like quartz in order to run the task at regular intervals. What does the servlet really do ? It sends you a report ?

Comment: yes ,it gives me the count of the user created per day and also the count of the total users in my database .

Comment: huuu? Can you describe the FULL architecture of your system. I'm lost.

Comment: @Twister i m new to java and in learning phase sir and really dont konw much about the servlets.

Comment: The problem is not about servlet. What is the application your are talking about ? (ps : it is a bad idea to delete your comments, especially comments I answered to)

Comment: @twister when user will hit the application,he will get all details like how much users are created today,how much users are craeted till now etc.and i want to run the servlet run in background contineously so that the user could get the updates.I kno this is not the proper explation.(ps:i know it was a bad idea.sorry for that .)

Comment: @pritsag You may attach user date/time of creation to user account in your database and count it on the fly when user hit a button on the web page. This is more powerful and flexible since you can decide which interval you what to count. However, if you really want a cron-like system, e.g. every day, every hour, etc., you may use quartz to run a task on a certain interval.

Comment: @gigadot thanks for your kind reply sir.actually i have implemented the method in servlet which is giving me the count perfectly.but the thing now i want is actually instaed of running the servlet on daily basis i want to keep it running continweously so that whenever the request for updates about the count is sent, the response will be sent to user.

Comment: @pritsag I think I now understand what you want. You don't understand the purpose of servlet and how it works. that's not your fault. I suggest you read answer by @BalusC carefully. That's what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can use cron4j. http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/cron4j/manual.php

Answer (score 1):

Implement two classes and call `startTask()` in `main`.

```
public void startTask()
{
    // Create a Runnable
    Runnable task = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                runTask();
            }
        }
    };

    // Run the task in a background thread
    Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(task);
    // Terminate the running thread if the application exits
    backgroundThread.setDaemon(true);
    // Start the thread
    backgroundThread.start();
}

public void runTask()
{
    try {
        // do something...         
        Thread.sleep(1000);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is definitely NOT the way to do it in a web application - look at the answer above by @BalusC instead - he is correct here and I would say you can trust all of his answers.

Answer (score 0):

In a production system that may have multiple non-jee containers running. Use anot enterprise scheduler like  Quartz scheduler which can be configured to use a database for task maamgememt.