# HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method is not supported by this URL

Tags: servlets, http-get, http-status-code-405

I have the following servlet:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 16252534;
    private static int ping = 3000;
    private Thread t;
    private static boolean shouldStop = false;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();

        t = new Thread(new Runnable() { 
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(!shouldStop) {
                    System.out.println("Now:" + System.currentTimeMillis());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(ping);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();

    }
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        super.doGet(req, resp);
        System.out.println("doGet");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><h1>It works!!</h1></html>");
    }

    @Override
    public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        super.service(req, resp);
        System.out.println("service");

    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        super.doPost(req, resp);
        System.out.println("doPost");

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        super.destroy();
        System.out.println("Destroy servlet");
        shouldStop = true;
    }
}
```

Which is mapped as follows in my `web.xml`:

```
<display-name>MyServer</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.myserver.MyServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>      
   <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When I open my browser (Chrome) on `http://localhost:8080/MyServer/MyServlet`, then I see "service" from `doService()` being logged on console and my thread works correctly, however I don't see "It Works" from `doGet()` being logged and I get the following error in the browser:

> HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This is the default response of the default implementation of `HttpServlet#doXxx()` method (`doGet()`, `doPost()`, `doHead()`, `doPut()`, etc). This means that when the `doXxx()` method is not properly being `@Override`n in your servlet class, or when it is explicitly being called via `super`, then you will face a HTTP 405 "Method not allowed" error.

So, you need to make sure that you have the `doXxx()` method properly declared conform the API, including the `@Override` annotation just to ensure that you didn't make any typos. E.g.

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // ...
}
```

And you also need to make sure that you don't ever call `super.doXxx()` in your servlet method:

```
super.doGet(request, response);
```

Your servlet has this. Just get rid of this line and your problem shall disappear.

The `HttpServlet` basically follows the [template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) where all non-overridden HTTP methods returns this HTTP 405 error "Method not supported". When you override such a method, you should **not** call `super` method, because you would otherwise still get the HTTP 405 error. The same story goes on for your `doPost()` method.

This also applies on `service()` by the way, but that does technically not harm in this construct since you *need* it to let the default implementation execute the proper methods. Actually, the whole `service()` method is unnecessary for you, you can just remove the entire method from your servlet.

The `super.init();` is also unnecessary. It's is only necessary when you override the `init(ServletConfig)`, because otherwise the `ServletConfig` wouldn't be set. This is also *explicitly* mentioned in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#init-javax.servlet.ServletConfig-). It's the only method which requires a `super` call.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, spawning a thread in a servlet like that is a bad idea. For the correct approach, head to [How to run a background task in a servlet based web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691132/how-to-run-a-background-task-in-a-servlet-based-web-application)

Comment: Thank you very much. I've used ServletContextListener. One question: why using Thread in servlet is a bad idea?

Comment: It's not necessarily bad, but the way as you wrote code consumes 100% CPU resources forever. You should rather use a threadpool and a scheduler as outlined in the linked answer. And a `ServletContextListener` is simply the right place to do global initialization and cleanup during webapp's startup and shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

you have overridden the `service` method which is responsible to delegate the call to doGet or doPost. [see this for more details](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/ServletsFaq#9)
Also get rid of super.doxxx(..) calls from each method.
Don't override the `service` method and you should see, "It Works" from doGet.