# doGet Method of the Faces Servlet

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, servlets

I'm using Apache Tomcat 7.0 Servlet Container. I've been trying to look at the request handling in JavaServer Faces. I can see the following chunk of config in the web.xml :

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

I've looked at the source of the Faces Servlet, but I haven't found `doGet` method inside. I thought doGet method is one of the principal method to handle `HTTP GET` request in the Java Servlets. So who exact handles incoming `GET` request in JSF? I would like to look at the method, which do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`FacesServlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet.html) doesn't extend from [`HttpServlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) class containing a.o. [`doGet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doGet(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)). It just implements [`Servlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html) interface which offers the base [`service()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html#service(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse)) method. [Look here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.faces/javax.faces-api/2.2/javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet.java#FacesServlet.service%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest%2Cjavax.servlet.ServletResponse%29).

JSF is designed to be compatible with both servlets and portlets. Portlets doesn't use `HttpServlet`, but `PortletServlet` which shares the common `Servlet` interface.

Comment: That is, service method will be called when http request is come to a server, won't it?

Comment: Yup. Have you looked in source code of [`HttpServlet`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.0.1/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.java#HttpServlet.service%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%2Cjavax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29)? Check when exactly `doGet()` will be called. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370633/405-http-method-get-is-not-supported-by-this-url/ for related answer on that part.

Comment: Yes, I do. It seems core of the method is starting JSF lifecycle and further rendering page with `lifecycle.execute(context); lifecycle.render(context);`

Comment: Yup. Don't forget to click the `service()` link in my answer for the definitive answer.

Comment: I've found `lifecycle = lifecycleFactory.getLifecycle(lifecycleId);` inside the `init()` method body. Is `lifecycle` object destroyed after the request handling is completed?

Comment: This is a different question. Just look at the source code and read Servlet API specs/javadocs or press `[Ask Question]` button. In the meanwhile, this may be helpful to get better insight into basic servlet API: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading/