# Run servlet continuously

Tags: servlets

In my program the database keeps updating every second.
I want to create a servelet that keeps on running contiunosly 
and fetches data fron database every second.
How can I build it?

Comment: I don't think you want a servlet, what do you want to do with the data when you return it?

Comment: send it as xml file to an ip

Comment: You can build it with java. That's not a very good answer I know. But you didn't ask a very good question. Please make it more clear what you are looking for.

Comment: Here is the details of what i want:

1)The servlet will keep on receiving xml files continuously. 
2)Based on that input, servlet will make changes to the database. 
3)Then the servlet will generate another xml file and send it to an ip address. 
4)This process will keep on repeating until the data in the input xml file tells it to stop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to keep the servlet continously running?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691132/how-to-keep-the-servlet-continously-running)

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning on running a scheduled task in a Java EE container then the best thing is to use the Timer Service to schedule your job.

I suggest [reading the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html) to start and then having a go.  If you then get stuck, ask for more help.