# How I add dynamic text from database to jsp page?

Tags: javascript, java, html, mysql, jsp

I am trying to achieve a Notice/Bulletin board feature where text will be updated from database which will help the users to get latest updates (similar to university websites)

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to display data? or how to fetch data?

**To fetch data from DB:**
It's very basic and simple job, just follow the flow of data carefully,
Your JSP page would call a servlet, further servlet would send DB connection to java file and call one of its methods.
*JSP could call servlet for specific action (loading/refresh)
**- or -**
It could be scheduled to get the latest info after a specific time interval.
*

Call: -> 
**1.jsp -> 2.servlet -> 3.java method**

java method return data (String or JSONObject(*prefered for a large amount of data*)),
accepted by the servlet and sent further to JSP page.

Why use servlet then?
A servlet is a Java class used to help servers via request-response programming model.
Example: Establish connection and send connection to java method( which execute/update query)

Return: ->
**3.java method(query's result) -> 2.servlet -> 1.jsp**

**To display data**
Just use received response with JS or JQuery to insert into your webpage view.

**Links:**

More about servlets: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnafe.html

Call servlet periodically: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26437201/7190541