# How to start @Schedule method in Java EJB in Tomcat

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I have a Java Servlet running in Tomcat8 (within eclipse). When the Servlet is called I would like to execute a command and call a method, that uses a Scheduler.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Scheduler s = new Scheduler();
        s.doStuff();
```

.

```
 package xy;
 import javax.ejb.Schedule;
 import javax.ejb.Singleton;

  @Singleton
  public class Scheduler {

    private int counter = 0;

    @Schedule(second = "*/5", minute = "*", hour = "*", info="Every 5 seconds")
    public void  doStuff(){
        counter++;
        System.out.println("counter: " +counter);           
    }
}
```

Following my logic, every 5 seconds I should see a counter println getting higher and higher. But nothing happens.

Comment: Tomcat is not EJB container

Answer (score 3):

Tomcat is not a complete Java EE container. It implements only the Java Servlet and JavaServer Pages technologies, so you will not be able to use EJBs (`@Singleton`) or the Timer Service (`@Schedule`). Consider using a Java EE server or [ScheduledExecutorService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691132/how-to-run-a-background-task-in-a-servlet-application/4691650#4691650).

#### See also

- [How to run a background task in a servlet application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691132/how-to-run-a-background-task-in-a-servlet-application)

Answer (score 2):

**Tomcat is not EJB container**

The most simple way to do scheduled execution in tomcat - use `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService`.

```
@WebListener
public class MyAppContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        //init sheduler
        scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        //!!!Shedule task
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(...);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        scheduler.shutdownNow();
    }
}
```

To shedule task uses:

```
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(command, initialDelay, period, unit);
```

`command` - Instance of class which implements `java.lang.Runnable`

`initialDelay` - delay before first run in time units

`period` - time in units between task executions

`unit` - `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit` (ex. `TimeUnit.MINUTES`)

Answer (score 1):

Try jboss open src free version OR http://tomee.apache.org/ Tommy, it has tomcat underneath. Like others have said tomcat is not a full app container.

Comment: Did TomEE used to be called Geronimo or does Apache really have two competing JavaEE servers?

Comment: @Powerlord http://tomee-openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/Is-geronimo-dead-td4666924.html