# Scheduling in jboss7 (and in wildfly) without using EJB

Tags: jboss7.x, wildfly

I want to use scheduling in jboss7 (and in wildfly) but I don't want to use any EJB. I know the EJB @Schedule can be used but I have a web application and the same WAR should be used in Tomcat too so EJB is out of the question.
What can I use for scheduling?

Thanks,
V.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691132/how-to-run-a-background-task-in-a-servlet-based-web-application/4691650#4691650 but realistically you're throwing away a huge chunk of code on the Wildfly side.  Have two different distributions so that on Tomcat you use the ScheduledExecutorService hack and on on full JEE environments you use the tools available.  Ultimately then it is a build/distribution issue.

Comment: Third party solution such as Quartz may be?

Comment: I am little bit afraid of the unmanaged threads in an app server. Is there any impediment to put EJB in a JAR? I know usually it should be put to a JAR but can it be put to WAR too? Will Wildfly recognise it and use it as an EJB?