# Refresh Primefaces JSF page on running a servlet

Tags: jsf, servlets, primefaces

I have an app with a JSF page (the app uses Primefaces 5.1, Apache MyFaces 2.0, Tomcat 7, Java SE 8).

A servlet associated with the app is run once in a while; this needs to update some data on the JSF page. I can get reference to the app's session bean that is wired to the JSF page and update the data in the bean (from the servlet). This does not refresh the JSF page. When I do the browser refresh the JSF view gets refreshed with updated data.

How do I refresh the JSF page when I run the servlet (without the browser refresh action)?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4691132

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Right now I don't know what is going to be the solution for my app. I am looking into the mentioned solutions and I will post about how I am going to implement the solution in a day or two.

Comment: I tested a solution (an example) using Omnifaces-2.5.1 **o:socket** (the app uses Primefaces 5.1, Apache MyFaces 2.2.11, Tomcat 7.0.65, Java SE 8, Weld 2.3). This works as I wanted; I could update the JSF page from the Servlet dynamically. I will post some code later on.

Comment: It's already answered in the duplicate question.