# Should I create executorService within a request or share one instance across the webapp?

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

I am adding a new endpoint to a Jersey-based web-service. The logic backing the endpoint needs to make between 10 to 50 calls to another service. The calls are independent and can be parallelized, so I was thinking of using executor service to distribute the work across multiple threads.

I am wondering if I should instantiate an executorService for each request or should there be a shared executorService instance across the webapp. In the later case, how would I decide the number of threads it should run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am wondering if I should instantiate an executorService for each
>   request or should there be a shared executorService instance across
>   the web app. In the later case, how would I decide the number of
>   threads it should run?

No. In general, you should NOT instantiate the `executorService` for each web request (option-1) because the server will soon run out of memory and also, thread pool creation on the fly is costly (time-consuming).

So you need to go with the shared instance (option-2) of the `executorService` by creating it during server startup & configure the thread pool size according to your requirements and by conducting the performance tests.

You can refer [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html) to understand on the thread pools.

Comment: What is the best approach to implement the option 2? Share the executorService creating it  in (by example) a controller like a static field? Or do you think there is better way to share the ExecutionService?

Comment: @developer then how come all of the examples online (eg: [the part of this answer that uses `ScheduledExecutorService`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4691650/3684479)) make the `ScheduledExecutorService` private rather than public? From what you are suggesting here, it should be public so that it can be accessed throughout the app, right?