# Parallel processing using collection of CompletableFuture supplyAsync then collecting results

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-8, completable-future

```
//Unit of logic I want to make it to run in parallel
public PagesDTO convertOCRStreamToDTO(String pageId, Integer pageSequence) throws Exception {
    LOG.info("Get OCR begin for pageId [{}] thread name {}",pageId, Thread.currentThread().getName());
    OcrContent ocrContent = getOcrContent(pageId);
    OcrDTO ocrData = populateOCRData(ocrContent.getInputStream());
    PagesDTO pageDTO = new PagesDTO(pageId, pageSequence.toString(), ocrData);
    return pageDTO; 
}
```

Logic to execute convertOCRStreamToDTO(..) in parallel then collect its results when individuals thread execution is done

```
List<PagesDTO> pageDTOList = new ArrayList<>();
//javadoc: Creates a work-stealing thread pool using all available processors as its target parallelism level.
ExecutorService newWorkStealingPool = Executors.newWorkStealingPool(); 
Instant start = Instant.now();
List<CompletableFuture<PagesDTO>> pendingTasks = new ArrayList<>();
List<CompletableFuture<PagesDTO>> completedTasks = new ArrayList<>();
CompletableFuture<<PagesDTO>> task = null;

for (InputPageDTO dcInputPageDTO : dcReqDTO.getPages()) {
    String pageId = dcInputPageDTO.getPageId();
    task = CompletableFuture
            .supplyAsync(() -> {
                try {
                    return convertOCRStreamToDTO(pageId, pageSequence.getAndIncrement());
                } catch (HttpHostConnectException | ConnectTimeoutException e) {
                    LOG.error("Error connecting to Redis for pageId [{}]", pageId, e);
                    CaptureException e1 = new CaptureException(Error.getErrorCodes().get(ErrorCodeConstants.REDIS_CONNECTION_FAILURE),
                            " Connecting to the Redis failed while getting OCR for pageId ["+pageId +"] " + e.getMessage(), CaptureErrorComponent.REDIS_CACHE, e);
                    exceptionMap.put(pageId,e1);
                } catch (CaptureException e) {
                    LOG.error("Error in Document Classification Engine Service while getting OCR for pageId [{}]",pageId,e);
                    exceptionMap.put(pageId,e);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOG.error("Error getting OCR content for the pageId [{}]", pageId,e);
                    CaptureException e1 = new CaptureException(Error.getErrorCodes().get(ErrorCodeConstants.TECHNICAL_FAILURE),
                            "Error while getting ocr content for pageId : ["+pageId +"] " + e.getMessage(), CaptureErrorComponent.REDIS_CACHE, e);
                    exceptionMap.put(pageId,e1);
                }
                return null;
            }, newWorkStealingPool);
    //collect all async tasks
    pendingTasks.add(task);
}

//TODO: How to avoid unnecessary loops which is happening here just for the sake of waiting for the future tasks to complete???
//TODO: Looking for the best solutions
while(pendingTasks.size() > 0) {
    for(CompletableFuture<PagesDTO> futureTask: pendingTasks) {
        if(futureTask != null && futureTask.isDone()){
            completedTasks.add(futureTask);
            pageDTOList.add(futureTask.get());
        }
    }
    pendingTasks.removeAll(completedTasks);
}

//Throw the exception cought while getting converting OCR stream to DTO - for any of the pageId
for(InputPageDTO dcInputPageDTO : dcReqDTO.getPages()) {
    if(exceptionMap.containsKey(dcInputPageDTO.getPageId())) {
        CaptureException e = exceptionMap.get(dcInputPageDTO.getPageId());
        throw e;
    }
}

LOG.info("Parallel processing time taken for {} pages = {}", dcReqDTO.getPages().size(),
        org.springframework.util.StringUtils.deleteAny(Duration.between(Instant.now(), start).toString().toLowerCase(), "pt-"));
```

Please look at my above code base todo items, I have below two concerns for which I am looking for advice over stackoverflow:

> 1) I want to avoid unnecessary looping (happening in while loop above), what is the best way for optimistically I wait for all threads to complete its async execution then collect my results out of it??? Please anybody has an advice?
>
> 2) ExecutorService instance is created at my service bean class level, thinking that, it will be re-used for every requests, instead create it local to the method, and shutdown in finally. Am I doing right here?? or any correction in my thought process?

Comment: What's the point of returning a `Supplier` in `convertOCRStreamToDTO()`?

Comment: @didier-l Yep, I have no point returning `Supplier` in `convertOCRStreamToDTO()`, I updated my sample code above, please suggest how can I avoid unnecessary looping at while loop?? Any better way to collect the result as soon as thread completes its execution??

Comment: Concerning the question about the `ExecutorService`, that would be better asked as a separate question – which is likely to be already answered somewhere here on SO so please search first to avoid creating a duplicate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove the `while` and the `if` and you are good:

```
for(CompletableFuture<PagesDTO> futureTask: pendingTasks) {
    completedTasks.add(futureTask);
    pageDTOList.add(futureTask.get());
}
```

`get()` (as well as `join()`) will wait for the future to complete before returning a value. Also, there is no need to test for `null` since your list will never contain any.

You should however probably change the way you handle exceptions. `CompletableFuture` has a specific mechanism for handling them and rethrowing them when calling `get()`/`join()`. You might simply want to wrap your checked exceptions in `CompletionException`.

Comment: you are the man! Awesome. It solved my doubt. Exception handling this way `futureTask.completeExceptionally(e1)` I am exploring more to handle it. You solved my concern primarily I had.

Comment: @ravibeli: [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: @didier-l For #2 I searched in SO nobody asked the same question, I am waiting for answer to my question #2

Comment: @ravibeli [Should I create executorService within a request or share one instance across the webapp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42884255/should-i-create-executorservice-within-a-request-or-share-one-instance-across-th) – other similar questions exist, [Google is your friend](https://www.google.be/search?hl=fr&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&q=java+8+create+executor+service+in+each+request&gws_rd=cr&ei=ohzyWNzwB8fdwAK0nLSoBQ#hl=fr&q=java+create+executor+service+in+each+request) :-)

Comment: :-) Ok I got it. I am using Dropwizard framework with spring integration, I have created executor service instance at context level to re-use the same instance, which it right way to do as the point I read in the link you provided.