# Timer service only and only with CDI

Tags: jetty, scheduled-tasks, cdi

I am trying to build a web application using JSF 2.2, JPA 2.1 and CDI without EJB, since my application should deploy on Jetty server which doesn't support EJB in its 9th version.
I have searched a lot, not found any answer.. I need to schedule some CDI events in my application, without the use of @Schedule and other services offered by EJB.. 
Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Search Google for a Independent scheduling framework like quartz

Comment: Don't know if it is supported in Jetty, but have you tried with [batch](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/batch-1965499.html) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a background task in a servlet based web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691132/how-to-run-a-background-task-in-a-servlet-based-web-application)

Comment: Thank's all, @Leonardo no I didn't, I'll try the scheduler module first.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at **Apache DeltaSpike** [scheduler module](https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/scheduler.html). Should be supported on Jetty. You can also write Your own custom extension for CDI if this is not covering Your needs.