# How can I send POST requests from a background service in Java?

Tags: java, http, post

I'm currently working on a Java application that reads from Table A (with BLOB stored), writes some data from table A to table B while uploading the BLOB data to a file server. I tested the application on a test database(with around 400 rows) and it works fine. I need to implement the application as a background service that reads table A and sends HTTP POST requests to a REST server, followed by an insertion to table B and upload to file server. After the POST request, the server needs to return HTTP 202 created. I tried something like this:

```
@POST
@Path("attachments")
public void moveToMinio() throws Exception {
    TiedostoDaoImpl tiedostoDao = new TiedostoDaoImpl();
    List<Integer> id = tiedostoDao.getDistinctCustomerId();
    for (Integer userId : id){
    AttachmentService.insertAndUploadService(userId);
    }
}
```

tiedostoDao.getDistinctCustomerId() returns a list of distinct customer id from table A and passes that id to AttachmentService.insertAndUploadService() inside a for loop. This somehow gets the job done, but I doubt this isn't the right way as it returns HTTP 200 and not 202. Is this right way to send a POST request? The production database may have millions of rows, what's the right way to process all those rows without affecting the server efficiency? I've been stuck with this for a while as I'm a java newbie and would really appreciate any help/suggestion.

Comment: What is your ultimate question? Returning 202? Having max. efficiency? Or any other thing I miss in the question?

Comment: @vahdet my ultimate question is how can I implement my application as a background service that sends POST requests to the server and returns an HTTP 202 response.

Comment: Do you just need the method moveToMinio to return 202 response?

Comment: @Azarea Yes. When the POST request is sent to /attachments, it starts to process the rows. There could be millions of rows and for every row processed it should return an HTTP 202 accepted with an upload link from the file server.

Comment: @RoshanUpreti but this method is a sync one, in this case only after all the userid are inserted and uploaded you can get a http code like 202.

Comment: @Azarea Thank you for clearing that up for me. How can I implement something that will give me HTTP 202 after processing each userid?

Comment: @RoshanUpreti if you want a http 202 after processing each userid, in this case you will have to make millions of http request, is this really worthwhile and practical? I'd prefer dump the upload link of each userid to db perhaps.

Comment: @Azarea you're absolutely right regarding the millions of requests. But, that is kind of my requirement. All rows processed need to return an HTTP 202. The background service definitely will consume a lot of I/O resources in the first run but after that, it will just snoop for the new incoming rows in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a http response after every row is processed, first you need to divide your method into which processes one row at one time, then you can use a Response to contain your http code and entity, like this:

```
@POST
@Path("attachments")
public Response moveToMinio() throws Exception {
    TiedostoDaoImpl tiedostoDao = new TiedostoDaoImpl();
    Integer userId = tiedostoDao.getOneCustomerId();
    String uploadLink = AttachmentService.insertAndUploadService(userId);

    return Response.status(Response.Status.ACCEPTED).entity(uploadLink).build();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. But wouldn't this only process one row at a time? I need to process the entire table.

Comment: @RoshanUpreti  But you can't have multi response in one http request

Comment: does this mean that I need to send individual POST request for each userId?

Comment: @RoshanUpreti yes, that's why i divide your method

Comment: Thank you again. I have a small question though. One userId could have multiple rows in the table. How would it work in that case?

Comment: @RoshanUpreti i think it depends on your requirement..either regard it as one userid or do sth else

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [How to run a background task in a servlet based web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691132/how-to-run-a-background-task-in-a-servlet-based-web-application)

Before you return response, put the job into a global queue and let the background  process do the job.