# How to kill a thread that was stated at the server start up which starts an infinite loop

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

I need to start a filewatcher service at the server start. The file watcher service starts in an infinite while loop. So I have started a thread to start the watch service in a loop by overriding the servlet init method. Now when I shutdown tomcat, this thread that is running the loop gets killed abrouptly. There is an error in tomcat logs which says that there is a memory leak issue.Is there a way to stop this thread when the server shutsdown

I have tried to override the destroy method and make while loop condition to false. But I noticed that the destroy method is not getting executed when the server shuts down.

```
public  static void startFileWatcher() throws InterruptedException {
        Runnable r = () -> {
            try {
                while (!exit) {
                    System.out.println("Exit flag: " + exit);
                    if (FileWatcherUtil.isFileChanged()) {

                        System.out.println("file is changed");
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                        InstantiateSystemProperties.destroy();
                        System.out.println("Initializing new system properties");
                        SystemPropertiesConfigurer.loadNewXml();
                        InitializeLogger.resetLogger();
                        InstantiateSystemProperties.initializeLoggerObject();
                        NotificationQueue.resetQueue();
                        InstantiateSystemProperties.startThreadPool();
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                logger.error("Exception in custom init(): ", e);
            }
        };
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.start();
        t.setDaemon(true);

    }
    public static void stopThread(){
        System.out.println("stopping th thread *********************************************************8");
        SystemPropertiesConfigurer.exit =true;
    }
```

Servlet destroy:
         @Override
            public void destroy() {
                System.out.println(".........destroy method invoked.......");
                InstantiateSystemProperties.destroy();
                SystemPropertiesConfigurer.stopThread();
            }

Comment: “I have tried to override the destroy method and make while loop condition to false.”  Was that condition stored in a `volatile` variable?  If not, were you using synchronization or a lock to make sure the changed value was seen in other threads?  See [this section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.3) of the Java Language Specification.

Comment: Also you could make your task responsive to interruption, check `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` in your loop. Then invoke `Thread::interrupt` on your thread in `Servlet::destroy` method.

Comment: VGR above makes a good suggestion. You can also check out the accepted answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106591/what-is-the-volatile-keyword-useful-for
Can you show us your code ? Or if you were able to fix your problem answer your own question ?

Comment: I have added the code snippet, I have used volatile variable

Comment: You're doing a `new Thread()` in a Java EE / Servlet based environment..?? STOP!! Please drop everything and redo based on https://stackoverflow.com/q/4691132

Comment: Thanks, I will redo my code with your approach. I have another doubt related to the timer, I have to schedule something at an interval of 1 sec, and this interval can change dynamically, how do I achive that. Currently, I am using a timer, it gets stopped if there is an user input and starts with the new values.