# Tomcat 7 Async Processing

Tags: multithreading, performance, tomcat, asynchronous

I am wondering how Tomcat 7 implements async processing. I understand that the request thread returns immediately, allowing the request thread to immediately listen for a new request and respond to it.

How is the 'async' request handled? Is there a separate thread pool that handles async requests? I assume blocking IO is handled using something like java.nio.Selector for performance. What about threads that are blocking on CPU calculations?

Comment: You may want to take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749350/illegalstateexception-not-supported-on-asynccontext-startasyncreq-res if you want to implement async processing on Tomcat 7. There is a twist.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You are mixing up different concepts. You must distinguish between:

1. **Asynchronous request handing as per Servlet 3.0**; an API that enables you to decouple an incoming servlet request from the web container thread pool. It does not create any threads on the fly. It's on the user of the interface to implement a proper multi-threaded solution. It does not relate to non-blocking IO.
2. **Thread pool**; provides a mechanism to obtain and manage threads in a web container. When it comes to *asynchronous request handing* you have 2 options. You can define your own [`ExecutorService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and use it to further process the request or you can create a new `Runnable` and submit it to the obtained `AsyncContext` by calling [`AsyncContext.start()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/AsyncContext.html#start%28java.lang.Runnable%29). In case of Tomcat the latter approach uses Tomcat's thread pool defined in `server.xml`.
3. **Non-blocking IO (NIO)**; Although it is *asynchronous* as well it is a different story. It relates to non-blocking IO operations like disk or network IO. If you want to enable NIO for HTTP request processing, have a look at Tomcat's [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html).

---

The below example outlines how it *can* work. It uses only one thread for worker jobs. If you run it from 2 different browsers in parallel the output looks like this (I use a custom logger):

```
   DATE                         THREAD_ID  LEVEL      MESSAGE
2011-09-03 11:51:22.198 +0200      26        I:     >doGet: chrome
2011-09-03 11:51:22.204 +0200      26        I:     <doGet: chrome
2011-09-03 11:51:22.204 +0200      28        I:     >run: chrome
2011-09-03 11:51:27.908 +0200      29        I:     >doGet: firefox
2011-09-03 11:51:27.908 +0200      29        I:     <doGet: firefox
2011-09-03 11:51:32.227 +0200      28        I:     <run: chrome
2011-09-03 11:51:32.228 +0200      28        I:     >run: firefox
2011-09-03 11:51:42.244 +0200      28        I:     <run: firefox
```

You see that the `doGet` methods immediately finish, whereas the worker still runs. The 2 test requests: `http://localhost:8080/pc/TestServlet?name=chrome` and `http://localhost:8080/pc/TestServlet?name=firefox`.

**Simple example Servlet**

```
@WebServlet(asyncSupported = true, value = "/TestServlet", loadOnStartup = 1)
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(TestServlet.class.getName());
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final int NUM_WORKER_THREADS = 1;

    private ExecutorService executor = null;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        this.executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_WORKER_THREADS);
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String name = request.getParameter("name");
        LOG.info(">doGet: " + name);

        AsyncContext ac = request.startAsync(); // obtain async context
        ac.setTimeout(0); // test only, no timeout

        /* Create a worker */
        Runnable worker = new TestWorker(name, ac);

        /* use your own executor service to execute a worker thread (TestWorker) */
        this.executorService.execute(worker);

        /* OR delegate to the container */
        // ac.start(worker);

        LOG.info("<doGet: " + name);
    }
}
```

**...and the TestWorker**

```
public class TestWorker implements Runnable {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(TestWorker.class.getName());
    private final String name;
    private final AsyncContext context;
    private final Date queued;

    public TestWorker(String name, AsyncContext context) {
        this.name = name;
        this.context = context;
        this.queued = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        LOG.info(">run: " + name);

        /* do some work for 10 sec */
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        ServletResponse response = this.context.getResponse();
        response.setContentType("text/plain");

        try {
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println("Name:\t\t" + this.name);
            out.println("Queued:\t\t" + this.queued);
            out.println("End:\t\t" + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            out.println("Thread:\t\t" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
            out.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        this.context.complete();

        LOG.info("<run: " + name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Regarding CometProcessor API, is there a thread that is polling all current connections to see which one has "data available for read"? To be specific, what would be the expected number of threads when there are 10 requests vs 100 requests? Assuming these are requests that have received BEGIN event, but have not received the READ event. http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/aio.html

Comment: @John If you are happy with home's answer, you should approve it. You additional question should be made a new question (eventually, you can make a reference to this one).

Comment: HI @JVerstry, to be honest I don't feel completely satisfied with the answer. I still don't feel like I have good understanding of Tomcat's architecture for for "async processing".

Comment: @John: If you want to fully understand the asnyc processing you must perform some research. This fairly complex concept can't be described in just one SO answer.

Comment: The ExecutorService also works in tomcat 5.5!! great! thanks for the post!