# IllegalStateException: Not supported on AsyncContext.startAsync(req, res)

Tags: java, asynchronous, process, request, servlet-3.0

I have created a servlet 3.0 to explore asynchronous request processing:

```
@WebServlet(name="MyTest", urlPatterns={"/MyTest"}, asyncSupported=true)
public class MyTest extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        AsyncContext tmp = req.startAsync(req, res);
        ...

    }    

}
```

but I get an `IllegalStateException` when `.startAsync(...)` is called. I know the Javadoc mentions that exception, but I did explicitly enable async (c.f. `WebServlet` annotation). I am using Tomcat 7.0.11.0 delivered with NetBeans.

I could confirm that `req.isAsyncSupported()` is returning false. What am I doing wrong? What more do I need to do to enable async processing?

**EDIT:**

I tried to implement the following [example](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=1437) and got the same issue.

Comment: I have now re-installed NetBeans 7.0.1, which comes with Tomcat 7.0.14, but I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I checked out Tomcat's code and saw that the asyncSupported variable has to be explicitly set to true. That's why you are getting `req.isAsyncSupported() == false`.

You could try to set the async attribute in the HttpServletRequest object to true by one of the following methods.

```
req.setAttribute("org.apache.catalina.ASYNC_SUPPORTED", true);
```

or

```
((org.apache.catalina.connector.Request)req).setAsyncSupported(true);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The request is not of type org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, but setting ASYNC_SUPPORTED to true works !!!

Answer (score 8):

Please check if you have any request filter which is not enabled to support async. Either you can remove the filter (temporarily) or mark it to support async.

Comment: Example (if you define your filter in web.xml); <async-supported>true</async-supported>