# Need sample code explaning Workmanager in Tomcat

Tags: multithreading, tomcat, asynchronous, workmanagers, commonj

I want to know how to use WorkManager in Tomcat 7. I came across the open source library **Foo-CommonJ** but nowhere i found a sample code explaning the usage.
The input parameter for FooWorkManager's constructor is an instance of commonj.work.work class, where as no one provides the **commonj.work.work** class (neither tomcat nor foo-commonj).
Basically i need a sample code explaining usage of WorkManager (FooCommonj jar) in tomcat.
And if Foo-Commonj doesn't support workmanager properly, then some alternative.

Comment: CommonJ is an implementation of the very old [JSR-237](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=237) that in the mean time has been withdrawn, so maybe it's not the ideal base for new work.  Have a look at [this SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745905/what-is-recommended-way-for-spawning-threads-from-a-servlet-in-tomcat) that has some recommendations wrt thread creation in a servlet container.

Answer (score 1):

JSR-237 has been withdrawn, but it has been merged with JSR-236.
http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=237 
Reason: JSR 237 has been merged with JSR 236, providing a single, consistent specification for Java EE concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

### Old school way

Copy to tomcat\lib folder following jars:

- commonj-xxx.jar
- tomcat-commonj-xxx.jar

In context.xml of your app or tomcat create a new WorkManager instance:

```
<Resource name="wm/myWorkManager" type="commonj.work.WorkManager" auth="Container"
      factory="de.myfoo.commonj.work.FooWorkManagerFactory"
      maxThreads="10"
      minThreads="5" />
```

Fetch this instance using JNDI. For example using web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
  <description>Work manager example</description>
  <res-ref-name>wm/myWorkManager"</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>commonj.work.WorkManager</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  <res-sharing-scope>Unshareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

Any other way should work.