# Websphere workmanager alternative

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, commonj

In my current project I see workmanager uses to process the thread in asynchronous.  We are getting getting rid off IBM products and start using Tomcat. I need some input to replace the workmanager with what. I see commonj api but need some thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

For simplest solution you can use WorkManager in Tomcat. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64767965/1193657) for example.

However since java 1.5 and JSR-236 it is better to use Executors instead of WorkManager.
My practice is to wrap CommonJ WorkManager with Executor facade when application is deployed to WebSphere. And on other platforms use Executors directly.

This is mostly because of legacy code support. New applictions should use Executors directly and forget on WorkManagers, as WorkManager in latest WAS is Executor implementation.

Spring is offering WorkManager Executor wrapper since like forever. It is called
[WorkManagerTaskExecutor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jca/work/WorkManagerTaskExecutor.html), and with it you can wrap your workmanagers in executors api.

Or to work with Executors and JSR-236 directly use [DefaultManagedTaskExecutor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/DefaultManagedTaskExecutor.html). On WAS JSR-236 executor is still implemented using WorkManager instance but that is now implementation detail instead.