# Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Ljavax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedThreadFactory

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, jakarta-ee

I added some code to my WAR project to use javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedThreadFactory and I'm now getting a NoClassDefFoundError.  I've attached the error message and my Maven pom change. I'm using WebLogic 12c with Java 1.7.

```
]] Root cause of ServletException.
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myComponent' defined in class path resource [my/package/bean.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'careCoordinatorRecipientListComponentRouter' while setting bean property 'inboundRouter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myComponent': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedThreadFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, mappedName=, description=, name=, type=class java.lang.Object, authenticationType=CONTAINER, lookup=)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'careCoordinatorRecipientListComponentRouter': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedThreadFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, mappedName=, description=, name=, type=class java.lang.Object, authenticationType=CONTAINER, lookup=)}
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedThreadFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, mappedName=, description=, name=, type=class java.lang.Object, authenticationType=CONTAINER, lookup=)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:920)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:789)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:431)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:409)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace


Maven change:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

My class that's using this code:

```
public class AsynchronousLinkedComponentRouter implements
        MessageDispatcher<Object, Object> {

    /**
     * The components reference.
     * 
     * @uml.property name="component"
     * @uml.associationEnd
     */
    private List<Component<Object, Object>> components;

    /**
     * Logger for this class.
     */
    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory
            .getLog(AsynchronousLinkedComponentRouter.class);

    protected ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> threadResultsMap;

    protected ConcurrentHashMap<String, ComponentException> componentExceptionsInThreads;

    @Resource
    private javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedThreadFactory threadFactory;

    /**
     * Set the components.
     * 
     * @param theComponent
     *            the component reference.
     */
    @Required
    public void setComponents(final List<Component<Object, Object>> components) {
        this.components = components;
    }

    /**
     * Route the message to the component.
     * 
     * @param message
     *            the message
     * @return the output after the component has processed the message
     * @throws RouterException
     *             if an error occurred when routing the message
     */
    @Override
    public Object route(final Object message) throws RouterException {
        try {
            threadResultsMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();
            List<Thread> producerThreads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
            for (final Component<Object, Object> component : this.components) {
                AsychronousMessageProcessorTask ampTask = this.new AsychronousMessageProcessorTask(
                        component, message);
                Thread producerThread = threadFactory.newThread(ampTask);
                producerThread.setName("Parent thread: "
                        + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " for component: "
                        + component.getName());
                producerThread.start();
                producerThreads.add(producerThread);
            }
            LOG.info("Created the producer threads, waiting to join the threads.");
            try {
                for (Thread thread : producerThreads) {
                    thread.join();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RouterException("Interruption while joining producer threads",e);
            }

            LOG.info("Joined all producer threads");
            if (componentExceptionsInThreads.size() > 0) {
                LOG.info("Detected exceptions thrown in "
                        + String.valueOf(componentExceptionsInThreads.size())
                        + " producer thread(s).");
                String oneExceptionKey = null;
                for (String k : componentExceptionsInThreads.keySet()) {
                    LOG.error(componentExceptionsInThreads.get(k));
                    oneExceptionKey = k;
                }
                // We can only throw one of the (possibly multiple) ComponentExceptions
                // The selected one to throw is not guaranteed to be the first.
                throw (componentExceptionsInThreads.get(oneExceptionKey));
            }
            List<Object> resultsList = new ArrayList<Object>(threadResultsMap.values());
            return resultsList;
        } catch (final ComponentException ex) {
            throw new RouterException(ex);
        }
    }

    private class AsychronousMessageProcessorTask implements Runnable {
        private Component<Object, Object> component;
        private Object message;

        public AsychronousMessageProcessorTask(Component<Object, Object> component,
                final Object message) {
            this.component = component;
            this.message = message;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                threadResultsMap.put(component.getName(),
                        component.processInbound(message));
            } catch (ComponentException e) {
                componentExceptionsInThreads.put(component.getName(), e);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: afaik weblogic 12 isn't a JEE7 container but a JEE6 container. So those classes won't be available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that WebLogic won't support JEE7's concurrent utitilities until version 12.1.4. At least for WebLogic, I'm told that the Work Manager API is a good option: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24413/toc.htm#COMMJ129
and:
[What is recommended way for spawning threads from a servlet in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745905/what-is-recommended-way-for-spawning-threads-from-a-servlet-in-tomcat)