# enable or disable menu item based on permissions of the user logged in with jsp and servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a jsp page which contains the same menu bar for everyone, each user has a permission depending on his status ( if he is an administrator or user ..) 
i want to disable some item menu bar if the user logged in is an administrator , and enable the other ones
 How can i achieve this, please suggest.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Set the role in session and get it in JSP page. In servlet,

```
session.setAttribute("Role", "administrator");
```

And in JSP,

```
<%
 String role= (String)session.getAttribute("Role");
 pageContext.setAttribute("role",role);
%>
```

Here I assumed that you are using [**JSTL**](https://jstl.java.net/) for standard (Just add this line `<%@ taglib prefix="c" 
           uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`).

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="{role == 'administrator'}">
        <!-- Menu Choice 1 -->
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <!-- Menu Choice 2 -->
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

See [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927967/creating-a-menu-with-navigation-links-with-jstl#5928182) answer for more details. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your help , but the result is always the second menu whatever is the user logged in . if we suppose that the first menu choice is for the administrator , and the user logged in is an administrator , i want to have the first menu choice enabled and the second one shown but it s disabled

Comment: Can you post your relevant JSP and servlet code by edit your question?

Comment: i couldn't post the code , it s too long and i had a problem with the format of the message , thank you any way for your help