# Is there a way to do something on a J2EE server-start? I'm using Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, servlets, event-handling, startup

I'm trying to get a J2EE server to register (read: send some message to) with another server on its own initiative - not as a response to something. Surprisingly, I've found very little information or questions on whether there are events and/or classes to extend that will give me a handle on "server-start". I could always write a script that first deploys to server, then prompts it with a request, but I'd really rather have a cleaner solution..

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implement [`ServletContextListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) and do the job in `contextInitialized()` method.

```
public class Config implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // Do stuff during server startup.
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // Do stuff during server shutdown.
    }

}
```

When you're using Tomcat 7, register it as follows to get it to run

```
@WebListener
public class Config implements ServletContextListener {
```

Or when using Tomcat 6 or older, register it in `web.xml` instead

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.example.Config</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: I wonder why the ServletContext mem-store is unavailable there. This doesn't seem very logical, and it's too bad, because I can't initialize attributes that will be available later on, too.

Comment: It's available by `event.getServletContext()`. See also [those answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a157882%20%22public%20class%20config%20implements%20servletcontextlistener%22), particularly [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468150/using-init-servlet/3468317#3468317).

Comment: Again, thanks a lot. I wasn't aware of that area in the API.