# Tomcat Java Servlet - Initialize Class on Application Startup

Tags: java, tomcat, classloader

I have a class that takes a bit of time to start up (makes some JNI calls and what not), so it is not feasable to initialize this class everytime a page loads. Is it possible to initialize this class on application startup, then access its methods as pages are being served up?

For Example:

I have MyClass. When the application (tomcat) starts up I would like it to initialze my calss as follows:

```
MyClass myClassInstance = new MyClass("arg1", "arg2");
```

Then when a page is called, say /testpage, I would like to make calls to myClassInstance:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import MyClass;

public class TestPage extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        String myResult = myClassInstance.getResult("whatever");

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Test</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>" +myResult +"</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468150/using-init-servlet, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153739/config-files-for-a-webapplication-load-once-and-store-where, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951294/is-there-a-way-to-do-something-on-a-j2ee-server-start-im-using-tomcat,  etc

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. Initialize your class in servlet's `init()` method. You may add `<load-on-startup>` attribute to make sure your servlet is created at application startup and not on first access.
2. Add `ServletContextListener` and use `contextInitialized()` callback method. Use [`ServletContext#setAttribute`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) to store created object for future use.

Comment: yeeessss! Exactly what I need. "<load-on-startup>"

Comment: More information on "load-on-startup": https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1039287

Answer (score 8):

If you want it to happen once for the whole app, and happen before any servlet is run, implement `ServletContextListener` and put your startup code in `contextInitialized()`.  Then set up your `web.xml` to specify your class as a listener.

Otherwise, you can do what the other answer says and put it in the `init()` method of the servlet.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the initialize of the class inside the servlet's `init` method.
`init()` method is invoked when the servlet instance is loaded so it is a good place for expensive operations.