# How to prevent JSF from initializing automatically?

Tags: jsf, tomcat, mojarra

When I create a web application from scratch and add jsf-api-2.2.11.jar and jsf-impl-2.2.11.jar to pom.xml (add them to apps classpath) and deploy it to Tomcat 7, JSf is initializing automatically:

```
INFO [j.e.r.w.j.config] - Mojarra 2.2.11 ( 20150505-0732 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.11@14688) ..... initialized.
```

In older versions I used to start it declarativly by defining it in web.xml (listener+servlet). So I already commented them out and set "metadata-complete" to "true" (does that even stop classpath scanning?), but it is still loading.

In this case I dont want it to load, while leaving the Jars in classpath and i.e. the faces-config.xml in web-inf.

What is still triggering the initialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's loaded via a Servlet 3.0 [`ServletContainerInitializer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html) implementation in the JSF implementation JAR file (in case of Mojarra, it's the [`com.sun.faces.config.FacesInitializer`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.2.0/com/sun/faces/config/FacesInitializer.java#FacesInitializer)). It will auto-register the `FacesServlet` on the URL patterns `*.jsf`, `*.faces` and `/faces/*` (JSF 2.3 will add `*.xhtml` to the list of URL patterns). Latest JSF 2.1 implementations and all JSF 2.2 implementations will do it when deployed to a Servlet 3.0 compatible container. For detail about this new Servlet 3.0 `ServletContainerInitializer` thing, head to this answer: [ServletContainerInitializer vs ServletContextListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10776599/servletcontainerinitializer-vs-servletcontextlistener/10784700#10784700).

The right way to stop it is removing the JSF implementation from the dependencies (note that you do not need to remove the JSF API as well). You seem to not be making use of it in any way. After all, a properly designed web application should not have any JSF implementation specific dependencies. I only wonder, why exactly would you leave the JSF API in? Using a 3rd party JSF based library for non-JSF purposes? This might indicate and end up in other (architectural) problems.

Another way of stopping it is downgrading your web application to be Servlet 2.5 targeted by editing the `<web-app>` root declaration in `web.xml` accordingly to comply that version. But this has many other side effects which may not be desireable when the intent is to develop a Servlet 3.0 compatible web application.

---

The "listener" you're referring to is actually not necessary, it's only to workaround buggy containers with timing errors in parsing TLD files, such as early GlassFish v3 and Jetty versions. See also a.o. [Configuration of com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264083/configuration-of-com-sun-faces-config-configurelistener).

Comment: Ok for point one, even though I really dont like my app to be auto configued, because of the structure of the classpath. For point two, I did remove the impl. That worked thanks, but I do want to leave the api in, because Ithe Jsf part of the app should not be removed. I would like to switch between JSF and different UI frameworks, using configuration.

Comment: OK, the enduser should then supply the JSF impl themselves – which is after all a much better idea in this construct, too.