# Understanding FacesContext instantiation details

Tags: jsf, lifecycle

Mojarra 2.2.12

Here is the piece of code taking over the instantiation of the [FacesContext](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.faces/jsf-api/2.1/javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet.java):

```
FacesContext context = facesContextFactory.getFacesContext
              (servletConfig.getServletContext(), request, response, lifecycle);
```

The expression is perfectly clear. Once we get a request, we acquire a global information from it and create the `FacesContext` instance using it. So, the instance is created for each request. But obtaining the intance of `facesContextFactory` seemed to me much more tricky.

```
// Acquire our FacesContextFactory instance
try {
    facesContextFactory = (FacesContextFactory)
        FactoryFinder.getFactory
        (FactoryFinder.FACES_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
} catch (FacesException e) {
    //others
}
```

Where

```
String javax.faces.FactoryFinder.FACES_CONTEXT_FACTORY = "javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory"
```

JavaDocs for the `FactoryFinder` describes the so called

> standard discovery algorithm for all factory objects specified in the
>   JavaServer Faces APIs.

This is what I was confused by.

Now, Let's consider the the actual method that creates the factory instance: [javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance#getFactory(String factoryName)](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.faces/jsf-api/2.1/javax/faces/FactoryFinder.java#FactoryFinder.FactoryManager.getFactory%28java.lang.ClassLoader%2Cjava.lang.String%29)

```
try {
      factoryOrList = factories.get(factoryName);
      if (!(factoryOrList instanceof List)) {
          return factoryOrList;
      }
} finally {
      lock.readLock().unlock();
}
```

The `factories` field is initialized as follows [copyInjectionProviderFromFacesContext()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-api/2.2.8/javax/faces/FactoryFinderInstance.java#FactoryFinderInstance.copyInjectionProviderFromFacesContext%28%29):

```
private void copyInjectionProviderFromFacesContext() {
    InjectionProvider injectionProvider = null;
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); //USE FACES CONTEXT!!!!!
    if (null != context) {
        injectionProvider = (InjectionProvider) context.getAttributes().get("com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager_INJECTION_PROVIDER_TASK");
    }
    if (null != injectionProvider) {
        factories.put(INJECTION_PROVIDER_KEY, injectionProvider);
    } else {
        if (LOGGER.isLoggable(Level.SEVERE)) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Unable to obtain InjectionProvider from init time FacesContext. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?");
        }
    }
}
```

So, creating used `FacesContext` instance, but the factory itself is used for creating the `FacesContext`. Couldn't you explain that cycle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a special "[init FacesContext](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.11/com/sun/faces/config/InitFacesContext.java#InitFacesContext)" which is available during servlet container initialization, ensuring that there's at least "a" `FacesContext` around during JSF initialization. This special "init FacesContext" has a lot of empty/null/default properties, particularly the ones depending on HTTP servlet request/response, but application and configuration related properties such as ones available via `FacesContext#getApplication()` are already available based on a.o. `faces-config.xml`.

In case of Mojarra, this "init FacesContext" is [created](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.11/com/sun/faces/config/FacesInitializer.java#130) in a.o. the [`com.sun.faces.config.FacesInitializer`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.11/com/sun/faces/config/FacesInitializer.java#FacesInitializer), a [`ServletContainerInitializer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10776599/servletcontainerinitializer-vs-servletcontextlistener) implementation which runs during webapp startup. During that moment, factories are created.

Comment: So, this is the case for creating InitFacesContext: `FacesContextFactory privateFacesContextFactory = (FacesContextFactory) FactoryFinder.getFactory("com.sun.faces.ServletContextFacesContextFactory");`? It doesn't appear in the [Mojarra 2.2.4](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-api/2.2.4/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.java#FacesContext.getCurrentInstance%28%29) though...

Comment: No, it's created in `FacesInitializer`. Click the "created" link in my answer.

Comment: How come I'm getting JSF related error when trying to run a Spring app on GF 4.1.1 without any references to Mojarra:
Info:   WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Info:   Initializing Mojarra 2.2.12 for context '/sm-shop-2.0.3-SNAPSHOT'
Severe:   Unable to obtain InjectionProvider from init time FacesContext. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?
Severe:   Unable to call @PreDestroy annotated methods because no InjectionProvider can be found. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?

Comment: @developer10: because GF is a Java EE server. I.e. it implements anything from Java EE API, including JSF. Normally, Spring applications are deployed to non-Java EE servers such as Tomcat. See also a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295096/what-exactly-is-java-ee

Comment: @BalusC Yes, I've been trying to run it with Tomcat but it's giving me hard time by not starting, etc. Is there any easy way to overcome this JSF related issue on GF (just to tell it to ignore/stop looking for JSF)?

Comment: @developer10: your concrete problem is just caused by classpath pollution, not by JSF. Perhaps you've for some reason a `javaee.jar` lingering around in your non-Java EE application. That's by the way most likely the same reason as why your Tomcat was giving troubles. I suggest to take a step back http://xyproblem.info

Comment: @BalusC Could it be just this one in Glassfish4/lib directory? Or there must be one in the project itself?

Comment: @developer10: in the project itself of course. You shouldn't touch the server's libraries.