# why exist initContextServletContext in JSF Mojarra 2.2 FacesContext.java

Tags: jsf, mojarra, facescontext

```
private static ConcurrentHashMap initContextServletContext = new ConcurrentHashMap(2);
```

field is private, but never used in FacesContext class. Is there a reason to exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's accessed by reflection in Mojarra-specific [`com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.11/com/sun/faces/config/InitFacesContext.java#InitFacesContext) implementation which is only used during container initialization (line numbers match Mojarra 2.2.11):

```
675    static Map getThreadInitContextMap() {
676        ConcurrentHashMap threadInitContext = null;
677        try {
678            Field threadMap = FacesContext.class.getDeclaredField("threadInitContext");
679            threadMap.setAccessible(true);
680            threadInitContext = (ConcurrentHashMap)threadMap.get(null);
681        } catch (Exception e) {
682            if (LOGGER.isLoggable(Level.FINEST)) {
683                LOGGER.log(Level.FINEST, "Unable to get (thread, init context) map", e);
684            }
685        }
686        return threadInitContext;
687    }
```

#### See also:

- [Understanding FacesContext instantiation details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32391917/understanding-facescontext-instantiation-details/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any recommended book or article about this?

Comment: Not about the implementation details. Just keep reading source code :)