# Where place code in Servlet on start up using Tomcat?

Tags: java

I have created a servlet and each time it is started up, it is required to run several threads of code to completion **prior** to accepting any incoming requests. 
The threads could take up to several minutes to complete and require to interface significantly with a database and the file system.

I am new to writing servlets and would like to know the best place to insert this code. i.e. is the servlet init() method the best (or an appropriate) place for this code?

Thank you
Simon

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using init servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468150/using-init-servlet)

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately for you, there is a class for just such an initialization.  In your web application, add a class which implements javax.servlet.ServletContextListener.  In your web.xml, you must add that listener class so that the web container can know to run it.

At that point, you have two methods you must implement:  contextInitialized and contextDestroyed.  You're guaranteed that it is launched exactly once at the start of your web application prior to accepting requests and exactly once at the end (assuming there are no serious errors).

If you want to wait for these threads to finish, then start them and use Thread.join to wait until their completion so that you don't start accepting requests until they finish.

For more information on how to implement a ServletContextListener, [see here](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/what-is-listener-servletcontextlistener-example/) for an excellent example.

Comment: Thank you Neil for reply. The webapp contains many servlets. Only one of the servlets requires to run this initial code. The other servlets can receive requests at the same time. Is the ServletContextListener still the right place for this?

Comment: How much time are we talking about here?  Unless it's something which takes an incredible amount of time to do, it is usually better to do it upon initialization of tomcat, so yes.  However, your other services won't respond to requests like this.  If that is very important then yes, you should use servlet init.  Just remember to call `super.init(config)` inside your init method ([source](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/servlet/ch03_03.htm)).

Comment: The reason for the long-running jobs is in order to carry out mainly transactions that did not complete when the web app was last shutdown or stopped. 
Spring declarative transactions are being used. Am not sure if this could also be done on shutdown?
The reason for shutting down a particular servlet is because configuration data is changed fairly frequently and read upon servlet startup in servlet.init() - which is not needed by other servlets. 
I guess (not sure) I could update config data dynamically by passing a separate request to the servlet?
or should a separate web app be the solution?

Comment: @SimonReeves No, I suppose if you used load-on-startup, then the work could begin immediately rather than wait for the first request.  I'm just worried about the implications of doing heavy work in servlet init since maybe it wasn't meant to be used that way.  Try doing it that way, and if you find strange behaviors, use a ServletContextListener instead and play it safe.