# Start function when start tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a txt file have a sequence of integer such as :
" 15 20 30 21 17 6 28 34 "
I read the file and put the number to a arraylist 
I want get the value with position in arraylist by a servlet when request to server.

But now I want read txt file as soon as server start . I've put the read file function on the constructor function of servlet but it not run.
Please help me.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a ServletContextListener to web.xml and implement your code in the method contextInitialized.

web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>my.something.MyServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Implementation:

```
public class MyServletContextListener implements javax.servlet.ServletContextListener {
    public void contextInitialized(final ServletContextEvent event) {
        // code
    }
}
```

Or just load the servlet on startup:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MySerlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>my.something.MyServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: or a servlet which loads on startup. Upvote.

Comment: True, depends on the needs and the implementation (servlet implementation can be changed). Updated the answer.

Comment: If I load the serlvet on startup , where I put the reading file function ? Thanks

Comment: this is NOT when tomcat starts...

Comment: This is executed after the ServletContext was initialised. Nowadays there are alternatives with CDI/EJB. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468150/using-special-auto-start-servlet-to-initialize-on-startup-and-share-application