# using servletContext besides Request for Java Beans

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

I'm doing a Webapp that retrieves some information from a database and stores it in a Java bean using the  "request" as  context , 
POST method  sends the  table's information when  executed.
I'd like to know if  it would be better to  create the bean as a   servletContext to avoid instantiating it every time there is a request from the clients and hopefully  reduce the time my application process the requests. I haven't found  information regarding using Java beans as ServletContext .
Thanks in advance! 
the original code
using Request:

```
public class ControleurServlet2 extends HttpServlet {

public void  init() throws   ServletException { 
//Empty   
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
//... ... ...    

//Instantiation des Objects  de chaque  Request envoyé par le Client  
ModelEtagere model1=new ModelEtagere();
request.setAttribute("model",model1);//Envoi de Model Bean vers la page JSP 
this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(VUE).forward(request, response);      }
```

the code 
 using ServletContext:

```
public class ControleurServlet2 extends HttpServlet {
//Initialisation bean Model1
ModelEtagere model1;

@Override
public void  init() throws   ServletException {
metier= new MagasinMetierImpl();    
model1=new ModelEtagere();
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

//ServletContext
ServletContext context=  getServletContext();
//    ...   ...  ...

context.setAttribute("model",model1);//Envoi de Model1 Bean vers la page JSP 
this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(VUE).forward(request, response);      
}
```

Comment: Is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/q/3468150

Comment: Interesting link ,thanks.