# In JBoss How do I trigger the code in my war?

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I currently have a jar file containing a RabbitMQ consumer and publisher, a Drools drl file and the code that sends the consumed messages through KIE and then publishes the results. We have been using this jar in a service with no issues. The jar file contains all of it's dependencies via a maven install phase.

So, I have been asked to deploy this jar to a JBoss EAP server we have running. I was told "just convert it to a war and copy it to the deployment directory, good to go"! Without investigating JBoss any further I did as I was asked. JBoss loads the war but the RabbitMQ consumer is not initiated. I went through the JBoss examples but did not find one similar to my project.

Which JBoss example is most similar to what I have outlined above?

Or what is the minimum config or code I need to instruct JBoss to call a specific class.method after loading the war?

**Solution Chosen:**
We decided to use the EJB annotations as described in the link [Using special auto start servlet to initialize on startup and share application data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468150/using-special-auto-start-servlet-to-initialize-on-startup-and-share-application)

Comment: Thanks. Since I am new to JBoss it may take me a while to understand each scenario listed in your link.

Comment: I read through that link and I don't understand the connection between those examples and my use-case described above. I assume I need to implement some type of "listener".